# How to print the image side by side in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, image

I have a data frame which has a title and image link. I wanted to print the title and corresponding image one by one. My data frame name is 'a'

[image]

```
for index, row in a.iterrows():
    print(row['title'])
    response = requests.get(row['image_link'])
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)
```

**Getting below output**

[image]

**Expected output:**

I need either one by one or side by side image

1. I wanted to print the first title and followed by the image. Same for second, third and other titles.

or

2. I wanted to print the first title and the image side by side. Same for second, third and other titles.

Expecting either one of the above output

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [matplotlib.pyplot.title](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html) if it is ok to have the title within the picture:

```
for index, row in a.iterrows():
    response = requests.get(row['image_link'])
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.title(row['title'])
```